# loading local file in <audio> tag working alternately

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic-framework, audio

I need to load local audio file into `<audio>` tag.

I did it with the following code.

**Let the user choose a file with:**

```
<ion-input type="file" (change)="laodLocalFile($event)">
```

**Prepare it for `<audio>` tag:**

```
laodLocalFile(event: any)
{    
  file_url = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  document.getElementById('audio_file').setAttribute("src", file_url);
}
```

**And use it as following:**

```
<audio id="audio_file" type="audio/mpeg" controls></audio>
```

I tried it with several different mp3 files. It worked several times, but most of the times it didn't work, without any warning or error.

What can be the issue?

Comment: Did you tiry  ``this.mediaSrc = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(file_url);`` ?

Comment: Thank you man! it works. Please make it a formal answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `domeSanitizer` and `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()`
this method bypass security and trust the given value to be a safe style URL, i.e. a value that can be used in hyperlinks or src

```
constructor(private domSanitizer:DomSanitizer) {    }
```

And in your method:
...

```
this.mediaSrc = this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(file_url);
```