# unable to access ionic application ts files on browser

Tags: debugging, ionic-framework, webpack, developer-tools

I was working on ionic project and i couldn't debug the code on web browser cause all am seeing is compiled js files and webpack is not available
has anyone experienced this before. any help is appreciated.

Comment: how are you running your dev serve? are you using `ionic serve` command?

Comment: Check if this solves your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71105382/loading-local-file-in-audio-tag-working-alternately

Comment: @NajamUsSaqib yes i am using ionic serve